# Python- Issue writing txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, text-processing

I am currently working on a proxy scraper just for fun however, I ran into an issue

**I want the output of the file to be save to a txt file which is in the following format**

```
185.98.232.22:8080
144.217.161.149:8080
103.106.57.174:8080
49.156.47.61:8080
179.109.144.16:44222
```

Currently when I try to write a txt file I **only** get tyhe first proxy and port not the remaining ones so I get this

```
185.98.232.22:8080
```

Below is my code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

proxyDomain = "https://free-proxy-list.net/"

r = requests.get(proxyDomain)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html.parser")

table = soup.find("table",{"id" : "proxylisttable"})

for row in table.find_all("tr"):
    colums = row.find_all("td")
    try:
        print ("%s:%s" % (colums[0].get_text(), colums[1].get_text()))
        Scrapped ="%s:%s" % (colums[0].get_text(), colums[1].get_text())
        file = open("newprox.txt","w")
        file.write(Scrapped)
        file.close()
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: `file = open("newprox.txt","a")`?

Comment: You open and overwrite the file in each loop iteration so only the last item should remain. What is `print`ed?

Comment: It worked to get all of the to write on the file however, they are all on one line is there a way to have one on each line?

Comment: Open the your file before you start looping

Comment: Yes, append `\n` to the end of string yiu write

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski where to I add the \n?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all if you want to loop and write you need to open your file in "append" mode, not "write", because the latter overwrites existing content (see [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open)). But you should not open/close in each iteration as this is ineffective.

As for multi line you need to append `\n` to each line of text written.

So you want this:

```
with open("newprox.txt","w") as file:
    for row in table.find_all("tr"):
        colums = row.find_all("td")
        try:
            Scrapped = "%s:%s" % (colums[0].get_text(), colums[1].get_text())
            print(Scrapped)
            file.write(Scrapped + "\n")
        except:
            pass
```

or make your `try` block look like this (same result really):

```
        Scrapped = "%s:%s\n" % (colums[0].get_text(), colums[1].get_text())
        print(Scrapped, end="")
        file.write(Scrapped)
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your code to match the following:

```
    file = open("newprox.txt","a")
    file.write(Scrapped + "\n")
```

Comment: It did work but there still seems to be a chunk on the top of the txt file that is not on a new line https://imgur.com/a/LtqamZw

Code https://imgur.com/a/MYlQaxh

Comment: delete your file "newprox.txt" and run it again